# Как добавить репозиторий qt?

Tags: linux, qt5

Дефолтный репозиторий содержит версию `qt` 5.5, а я хотел бы установить 5.10. Нашел репозиторий для линукса: `https://download.qt.io/online/qt5/linux/x64/online_repository/` - но, хоть я и добавляю его в список, при `apt update` выдает `404  Not Found`.

```
Ign:1 http://download.qt.io/online/qt5/linux/x64/online_repository qt InRelease
 Get:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [107 kB]                                                                                                                   
Hit:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                                                                                                                      
Err:4 http://download.qt.io/online/qt5/linux/x64/online_repository qt Release                                                                                                                
  404  Not Found
Hit:5 http://apt.llvm.org/xenial llvm-toolchain-xenial-5.0 InRelease                                                                             
Get:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease [109 kB]                                                        
Hit:7 https://repo.skype.com/deb stable InRelease                                                                                         
Hit:8 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                                      
Ign:9 http://packages.linuxmint.com sylvia InRelease                                                                 
Hit:10 http://packages.linuxmint.com sylvia Release                                                                  
Get:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease [107 kB]
Reading package lists... Done
```

Comment: так вы же напишите, какое именно описание вы добавили.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin в файл добавил строку: `deb http://download.qt.io/online/qt5/linux/x64/online_repository qt main` -

Comment: ну так в каталоге `http://download.qt.io/online/qt5/linux/x64/online_repository/qt` никакого apt-репозитория не наблюдается. и в [инструкции](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/linux.html) нет ни слова об этом. с чего вы вообще решили, что он там должен быть?

Comment: https://launchpad.net/~beineri/+archive/ubuntu/opt-qt-5.10.0-xenial

Comment: в bionic сейчас 5.9 заапгрейдитесь, если подходит 5.9